# jQuery will not run

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement fancybox and jqueryui's accordion into my site, I can NOT get fancybox to run. I am pretty certain that I am calling the function correctly but It just will NOT run!

Here is where I declare the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

the CSS

```
<link href="scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="scripts/fancybox/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Accordion Code
var ContentHeight = 480;
var TimeToSlide = 250.0;

var openAccordion = '';

function runScripts()
{
runAccordion(1);
logosize();
fancybox();
}
function fancybox()
{
    $(".fbox").fancybox({
          height:390,
          width:900
          })
}

function runAccordion(index)
{
  var nID = "Accordion" + index + "Content";
  if(openAccordion == nID)
    nID = '';

  setTimeout("animate(" + new Date().getTime() + "," + TimeToSlide + ",'" 
      + openAccordion + "','" + nID + "')", 33);

  openAccordion = nID;
}
//Logo Code
function logosize()
{
var logoID = document.getElementById('logo');
if (screen.width<=1152) 
{
    document.images["logo"].width = 175;
    document.images["logo"].height = 175;
    document.getElementById('AccordionWrapper').style.marginTop = '0px';    
}
}
//End
</script>
```

and the call:

```
<a class="fbox" href="about.html">This goes to iframe</a>
```

thepastebin for the whole thing is here: http://pastebin.com/eSQM6aX1

Any help would be great! Thanks...

Comment: Is runScripts executed after the document is ready?

Comment: <body onload="runScripts();">

Comment: You do not need `onload` when you use jQuery.  Just use `document.ready` function.  See my answer below.   (You also do not need _any_ inline JavaScript when you use jQuery.)

Comment: have tried that also, but that failed

Comment: Simply saying _"tried that, no good"_ does not help us to help you when you also have not posted anything we can see.  What's the error?  Is the `fancybox` plugin located in the path included on the page?  There are a million other things you could have done wrong.  Try it in Safari or Chrome and use the developer console.  JavaScript errors will show there.  Also construct a working demo in jsFiddle or put up a URL to your page so _we_ can see the problems.

Comment: ok sorry man! Ill get it online now. Stand by!

Comment: http://www.semaphoredesign.com/web-devel/joker/test2.html

Comment: I can't believe you can't see any errors in Firebug.  I'm seeing one major error, `'$(document).ready' [undefined] is not a function`,  because jQuery is not being loaded properly.  See my edited answer below.

Comment: Charlie, I spent some time trying to help you with this yesterday and then you vanished.   Are you still interested in a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry man, your advice worked and Made it all good to go! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run the fancybox function within itself.  You can't define a new function with the same name as the `fancybox()` function.

```
function runScripts() {
    runAccordion(1);
    logosize();
    fancybox();   // <--- the plugin is already using this function name
}

function fancybox() {
    $(".fbox").fancybox({
          height:390,
          width:900
    })
}
```

So you *could* just rename it...

```
function runScripts() {
    runAccordion(1);
    logosize();
    Myfancybox();
}

function Myfancybox() {
    $(".fbox").fancybox({
          height:390,
          width:900
    });
}
```

But all you really need to do it put it all inside a `document.ready` function...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    runAccordion(1);
    logosize();

    $(".fbox").fancybox({
          height:390,
          width:900
    });

});
```

Anything else you want to fire when the document loads can be put inside there as well. This eliminates the need for a `runScripts()` initialization script.  And jQuery eliminates the need for `body onload` as well as all other inline JavaScript.

---

**Edit after seeing OP's page:**

http://www.semaphoredesign.com/web-devel/joker/test2.html

The only error on the page.  You should have seen this in Firebug or the Developer Tools in Safari or Chrome.

> TypeError: Result of expression '$(document).ready' [undefined] is not
>   a function.

This means that jQuery is not properly loaded.  I suspect that `prototype.js` is conflicting with jQuery.

Remove `prototype` as I suggested before to see if it starts working.

Then follow the directions [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which explain exactly how to use jQuery with other libraries like `prototype`.  Note that the script loading order is important...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I got no errors, I tried running it through firebug but I am not the best at using that. I really dont get it, I can upload it (both versions) if you would be willing to look?

Comment: Well, you absolutely cannot put the `fancybox()` function inside the `fancybox()` function.  Presuming you've properly fixed that issue, it's likely you still have other issues.  You removed the `onload` function?

Comment: Have tried that also, cleared up the naming error and still have errorsa

Comment: @Charlie, Maybe you can put up a working demo someplace.  I also see you're using the `prototype.js` framework.  Try removing it to see what happens.  Like I said, you have a lot going on in that page.  Constructing a working demo in jsFiddle might force you to stumble across your own problem.

Comment: @Charlie, in my previous comment, I suggested removing `prototype.js` to see if the problem clears.